# reinstalling backed up WordPress to xampsite

Tags: wordpress

I built a WordPress with xamp offline server . I needed to build another one so I moved the first folder outside htdocs folder as a backup and installed a new wordpress which is now currently running. I need the other one to run also, so I copied it back to the htdocs folder.I have two WordPress folders now but only one is working..how can I fix this...thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the two wordpress sites are connecting to the same data base by default. To change this you will need to change the database prefix in `$wp-config.php`

Navigate to your `wp-config` file in your `wp-admin` folder
open with any text editor of your choice
change the `$table_prefix`  = `'wp_site2_'` to `'wp_yourChoice'`;
this would enable the wordpress websites connect to different databases.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your apache to show two websites?